# How To Get Webhook Event When A Product Was Importet From Fulfillment?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I created successfully an app with webhook and I recieve the events. But when I import a product from maybe zendrop to my store I dont get any events. So which webhook topic should I use to listen this event ?

I tested this without success:

```
fulfillments/create, fulfillments_events/create, products/create
```